# Clickonce application deployment, hiding password in app.config

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, app-config

I have an application that i deploy to a client.  In the config file there is a username/password that connects to a database.  This config file gets stored in their local directory on their computer. I don't want them to see the password.  How can i exclude the config to be installed on their machine or does it have to be there. and if so, how can I hide the password using encryption? thanks

Comment: Can you use windows authentication with the sql server so no passwords are needed?

Comment: I think directly use windows authentication with sql server also not secure since the end user can simply install an open source sql explorer to access the whole database with his account.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt, for example, the connection strings in your **app.config** file.

An example of an encrypted section from the **[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)**:

```xml
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAH2...</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The solution is working through mis installer. The question is how to call custom protected configuration provider in ClickOnce during deployment?